# MyBatis @Result map to self object instead of property

Tags: parameters, mybatis, ibatis

I need a pre-query to be executed for Filter condition and pass the results to do actual fetch.

```
Select * from Table_a where id in ( select id from Table_b where X=?)
```

MyBatis Mapper looks as Follows

```
@Select("Select * from Table_a where id in (#{id, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER})")
ClassA getA(Integer id);

@Select("select id from Table_b where X=#{xValue, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}")
@Results(value = { @Result( property = "this", column = "ID", one = @One(select = "getA")) })
ClassA getAfromB(String xValue);
```

How do I map the result to the entire Object Instead of a named parameter?

I know I can get instance of ClassB and use getter to ClassA. 
Is there a direct way? or 
a way to add Filter results like this is available with myBatis?

Comment: why are you not doing this in one select? `@Select("Select * from Table_a where id in (select id from Table_b where X=#{xValue, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}) ")
ClassA getA(Integer id);`

Comment: Just to have a more fragmented approach and maintain separate tables together

when changes are pertaining to tableB dosenot need to change in queries with tableA

Answer (score -1):

Indeed a single query is enough, and better avoid sub-select using a join:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A a JOIN Table_B b ON a.id = b.id AND b.X=#{xValue, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```